# Обращение к методу родительского класса из метода дочернего. Есть ли разница?

Tags: php, ооп

Есть ли какая-то принципиальная разница между parentclass::doParent() и $this->doParent() при обращении к методу родительского класса из метода дочернего?

```
<?php

class parentclass {

    function doParent() {
        echo 'parentclass::doParent()';
    }

}

class childclass extends parentclass {

    public function doChild() {
        echo 'childclass::doChild()';
        echo '<br />';
        parentclass::doParent();
        echo '<br />';
        $this->doParent();
    }

}

$obj = new childclass;
$obj->doChild();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

В данном конкретном случае разницы нет.

Но надо понимать, если дочерний класс будет переопределять метод `doParent`, то, очевидно, эти два способа дадут разные результаты